# Limit Google Doc add-on's access to documents

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-addon

Is there a way to install a [Google Doc add-on](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop) and limit its access, so it can only access specific documents that I have designated (rather than gaining access to all of my documents)?

I am trying to limit the risk, when using an add-on from an unknown author, and wondering what options are available to me.  If there was a way to install an add-on on an opt-in basis, so it only gains access to documents where I have enabled the add-on, that would provide some helpful risk mitigation.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't depend on you, the user installing the add-on. It depends on the add-on developer.

---

Google Editor add-ons are created using Google Apps Script. Google Apps Script project creators / editors might add a JSDoc annotation to limit the add-on access only to the document where the add-on was activated.

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
```

For details, see [Authorization for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization).

The add-on developer should tell their add-on audience the required permissions and explain why they are required. Still, the authorization process will show the OAuth authorization screen showing the authorizations that will be granted.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm confused by what I read there.  I don't know what it means for an add-on to get access only "to files in which the add-on [..] is used" (what determines whether a file is considered "used" by the add-on?).  Maybe if the add-on hasn't declared `@OnlyCurrentDoc`, the add-on only gains access to a document if I click on one of the menu items associated with that add-on while that document is open?  Can you help me understand the implications of the documentation there?  Or would it be better for me to ask a new question?

Comment: @D.W. IIRC I already answered that... not sure if it was on SO or if it was on mentoring session. Give me  moment to see if I can find the SO question

Comment: @D.W. This is not exactly the answer that I was looking for but it's  the same question follow-up [Do Add-ons Travel with Google-Docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/163083/88163)

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention to this!  I am struggling to understand the implications of that for my question and for security risks.  Does this mean that all Docs add-ons are already "opt-in" on a per-document basis, in the sense that the add-on only gains access to a document once a user clicks on a menu item to enable the add-on on that document, and the add-on doesn't have access to other documents where no one has clicked on the menu item?

Comment: It's not as simple as that because add-ons could install time-driven triggers. From a security risk perspective, one of these triggers might access all your documents, in Google Drive, when your computer is turned off.

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers!  I am confused by everything I have read.  I will ponder and see if I can figure out how to ask a more specific question.  I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: SO has a Google Apps Script chatroom,. It might not be too hard to make an add-on for personal usethat meets your needs. I will try to hang around there  this week.